# Editing key and value from each array of objs

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an very simple array of objs and I need to display both the key and value from each obj.

**Array**

```
sequence_break: [
        {
          "Step 4": "Step 6",
        },
      ],
```

I need to now display this on the page as `S4 -> S6`

Previously when working with an array of strings that also looked the same `["Step 2", "Step 3"]`, but this was easy to by using a v-for and then taking the strings and running:

```
S{{item.slice(5)}}
```

This removes the `Step` and space after it and then I just put an `S` in front of it to get the desired result.

I could've done something like `str = str.slice(0, 3) + str.slice(4)`, but I don't know if the number will ever be in double digits, so I figured adding the `S` was the safest bet.

Anyway, now I'm not sure how I would do that with this array of objs though and isolating the key and value from the obj. I don't know regex that well, but I'm not convinced that is the best option either.

**TL;DR:**
How to go about turning `[{ "Step 4": "Step 6" }]` to `S4 -> S6`.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reevaluate your data structures and the purpose they are serving.

The objects in the array are, in my opinion, are using a key value pair incorrectly.

Below is the code to do what you are asking:

```
const getStepDisplayText = (sequenceBreakArray) => {
    return sequenceBreakArray.map((sequenceBreakItem) => {
        let currentStep = Object.keys(sequenceBreakItem)[0],
            nextStep = sequenceBreakItem[currentStep];

        return `S${currentStep.split(" ")[1]} ->  S${nextStep.split(" ")[1]}`
    })
}
```

But consider how you might be able to get a cleaner, more simple solution by changing the structure of your data.

```
[
    {currentStep: "Step 4", nextStep: "Step 6"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Yeah, I had talked to our backend dev after this post and proposed a very similar data structure, but thnk you for this either way! I learned a lot here!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the digit and return a new string.

```js
const
    convert = object => Object
        .entries(object)[0]
        .map(s => 'S' + s.match(/\d+$/)).join('->'),
    sequence_break = [{ "Step 4": "Step 6" }];

console.log(sequence_break.map(convert));
```